# Grub errors after installation Elementary OS alongside windows

Tags: partition, dual-boot, grub

I installed Elementary OS alongside Windows 10 on the one logical partition / and `elf` partition. But when I reboot pc, I see `grub rescue` shell. I tried to type this commands:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos7)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub
insmod normal
```

on the last command i see error: `file /boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found`. I found normal.mod in folder `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/` and type:

```
insmod $prefix/x86_64-efi/normal.mod
```

and get error `invalid arch-dependent elf magic` After this I tried to re-install grub from live cd (while installation I saw that install x86_64 type instead of i386)
Arch is not important for me. I just want to return ability to use my pc. Please help.

```
fdsik -l :

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x935f4825

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048   1126399   1124352   549M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1126400 251660287 250533888 119.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       251662334 976771071 725108738 345.8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       446973952 976771071 529797120 252.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6  *    251662336 253614079   1951744   953M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda7       253616128 446959615 193343488  92.2G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: Have you tried using rEFInd as your EFI boot manager, so that at least you can boot an OS? I should be able to boot any OS which installed an EFI executable in your EFI partition.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, thank you for answering. I don't undestend what about you say, but I hope your answer will help someone else, who is stupid like me. Thank you. I already found the [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/616341/438465)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing difficult. No need to complicate anything!

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

And then:

```
sudo update-grub --output /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

But after this I have on Windows excess Disk E with EFI folder. Well, to hell with him

Comment: I feel "to hell with it" can be a bit missleading: If one were to actually remove the partition, as opposed to just ignore that Windows gave it a drive letter, the computer would no longer boot.